# Download file via ajax results in corrupted file

Tags: javascript, ajax, .net-core

I am trying to download the file using ajax and the file gets downloaded but it is corrupted , not sure where I am going wrong ? I am on .Net core 3.1 and browser chrome as well as edge. Any assistance?

Controller Code:

```
 public FileResult DownloadFile(string fileName)
        {
            //Build the File Path.
            try
            {
                string path = Path.Combine(this.Environment.WebRootPath, "Files/") + fileName;

                //Read the File data into Byte Array.
                byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

                //Send the File to Download.
                return File(bytes, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
```

Javascript Ajax Code

```
 $(function () {
        $("#FileDownload").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            console.log('Doing ajax submit');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home/DownloadFile",
                data: { "fileName": $("#fileName").val() },
                responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                success: function (data) {
                    var bytes = data;

                    //Convert Byte Array to BLOB.
                    var blob = new Blob([bytes], { type: "application/octetstream" });

                    //Check the Browser type and download the File.
                    var isIE = false || !!document.documentMode;
                    if (isIE) {
                        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
                    } else {
                        var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                        link = url.createObjectURL(blob);
                        var a = $("<a />");
                        a.attr("download", $("#fileName").val());
                        a.attr("href", link);
                        $("body").append(a);
                        a[0].click();
                        $("body").remove(a);
                    }
                    
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$.ajax doesn't have a `responseType` parameter, that is on the xhr object.
To set fields to the underlying xhr object you have to use `xhrFileds`, you can also use blob as the responseType so you don't have to create one yourself.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/DownloadFile",
            data: { "fileName": $("#fileName").val() },
            xhrFileds: {responseType: 'blob'},
            success: function (data) {                    
                var blob = data

                //Check the Browser type and download the File.
                var isIE = false || !!document.documentMode;
                if (isIE) {
                    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
                } else {
                    var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                    link = url.createObjectURL(blob);
                    var a = $("<a />");
                    a.attr("download", $("#fileName").val());
                    a.attr("href", link);
                    $("body").append(a);
                    a[0].click();
                    $("body").remove(a);
                }
                
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
```

Comment: FYI type in xhrFields twice.